# Android volley handling JSON nested arrays in Recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have been attempting to parse a JSON nested array into a `RecyclerView` without success.

Here is what I have so far:

```
JsonArrayRequest Req = new JsonArrayRequest(newurl, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        // Parsing json
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                // this grabs the first object id/description/events
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                LoadInfo info = new LoadInfo();
                info.setDescrip(obj.getString("description"));
                info.setID(obj.getString("id"));

                //get the events array
                JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("events");

                    for (int d = 0; d < jsonArray.length(); d++) {
                        try {
                            //get this specific events entry
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(d);
                            // from this events entry get "date"
                            info.setDate(object.getString("date"));

                            List.add(info);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // notifying list adapter about data changes
        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        hideDialog();
    }

});
// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(Req);
```

Here is the JSON that it is parsing:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "description":"Ggg",
    "events":[
      {
        "date":"2017-01-14 08:37:00.000000"
      },
      {
        "date":"2017-01-28 08:37:00.000000"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It successfully pulls the number of items, two, and adds them to the `RecyclerView`. It is also successfully pulling the data when I print it out the returned JSON. However, the problem is that I need it to display the two items as:

```
Description: Ggg
Date: 2017-01-14 08:37:00.000000

Description: Ggg
Date: 2017-01-28 08:37:00.000000
```

Notice that the dates are different. The above code only adds to the `RecyclerView` the last date for both entries:

```
Description: Ggg
Date: 2017-01-28 08:37:00.000000

Description: Ggg
Date: 2017-01-28 08:37:00.000000
```

I believe this is because the `List.add(info);` only adds the last date that it processed and sets it as the date for all of the items in the `RecyclerView`.

In conclusion, my question is how can I get the `RecyclerView` to display both items with the different dates?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

Adapter Code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomListAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<LoadInfo> userList;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<LoadInfo> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
        LoadInfo feedItem = userList.get(i);

        customViewHolder.description.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getDescrip()));
        customViewHolder.date.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getDate()));
        customViewHolder.id.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getLessonID()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != userList ? userList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView description, date, id;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            this.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            this.id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvid);
        }
    }
}
```

LoadInfo Code:

```
public class LoadInfo{

    private String id, date, description;

    public LoadInfo() {
    }

    public LoadInfo(String date, String id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setDescrip(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescrip() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` code.

Comment: Bryan - edited original question with Adapter code etc.

Comment: Try creating your `LoadInfo` object within the second `for` loop, instead of the first?